# How do I exclude posts from custom taxonomy from a custom post type archive?

Tags: custom-taxonomy, custom-post-type-archives

I am trying to exclude posts from a custom taxonomy from displaying on a specific custom post type archive. How can I accomplish that? Today, I do this on a per post basis which is not practical. Thanks so much!

```
    function exclude_taxonomy_from_archive($query) {
        if ($query->is_archive('my-post-type') && $query->is_main_query()) {
            $query->set('post__not_in', array('108747', '105590', '105592', '105594', '105596' ));
        }
    }
    add_action('pre_get_posts', 'exclude_taxonomy_from_archive');
```

Comment: How are the 5 post IDs you listed determined?  This can be done programmatically if the criteria is logically consistent.

Comment: Thanks for the response! Random IDs are generated per post and there is no way for me to determine what the ID will be for said post into the future. However, I do add the same custom taxonomy to each of these and future posts like them. I just cannot figure out how to exclude posts with that given taxonomy.

Comment: Understood.  I should have worded my question differently.  I believe your goal is to exclude ANY post that has ANY term for this particular taxonomy assigned, yes?

Comment: Exactly! FYI, I just realized my code also removes the post from the custom post type in the backend WordPress dashboard (undesired).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Several things to consider so let's look at each one individually:

**Preserve Admin Screens**

As written, your function affects every page for that post-type, including your admin screens which will hide your filtered posts from all post listings.

Test to see if an admin screen has fired the post type query with `is_admin()` and return early if so.  Your function is hooked to `pre_get_posts` and will fire several times on every page load so the concept of returning early and avoiding additional code is important to avoid performance problems.

**Post Type Archive**

Your use of `is_archive()` is not doing what you expect it to.  There are no parameters available for `is_archive()` so the `my-post-type` is ignored. https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/is_archive/

Using `is_post_type_archive( 'my-post-type' )` is the correct way to test if the query is your CPT archive page.  Return early if the query is not (!).
https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/is_post_type_archive/

**Exclude Taxonomy**

Adding a tax query argument to the main query using the "NOT EXISTS" operator will eliminate any post that has any term for your taxomomy. NOTE: Taxonomy query arguments are an array of array by design.
Tax query documentation: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/#taxonomy-parameters

Don't forget to update `my-post-type` and `my-taxonomy` with your actual slugs.

Putting it all together we get:

```
function wpse_exclude_mytaxonomy_from_archive( $query ) {

    // Three conditions that we want to exit early for
    if ( ( is_admin() ) || ( ! is_post_type_archive( 'my-post-type' ) ) || ( ! $query->is_main_query() ) ) {
        return;
    }

    // Modify the query to exclude posts with any My Taxonomy term
    $taxquery = array(
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'my-taxonomy',
            'operator' => 'NOT EXISTS',
        )
    );

    $query->set( 'tax_query', $taxquery );

}

add_action('pre_get_posts', 'wpse_exclude_mytaxonomy_from_archive');
```

Comment: jdm, this was a fantastic solution! I was really missing the mark here and the addition of the performance improvement is an added bonus. I really appreciate your help and attention to detail. Thank you very much, I could not have done it without you.

Comment: Happy to help - sorry it took awhile.  Vacations get in the way sometimes! Don't forget to mark it if this is an acceptable answer to your question. Cheers.

Comment: Vacation, alright, hope you had a great one! Thanks again, and I just realized how to mark it.

Comment: We did, thanks!  Then again, even a bad vacation can be better than a good day at work.